# what scenarios browsers ignore to check with server for file changed or not and uses stale content?

Tags: caching, asp.net-mvc-2

Currently I am working on implementing caching for static contents (css,js,images) for a asp.net mvc2 applcation. I want to know like what are the scenarios browsers ignore to check with server for file changed or not and uses stale content?

Can anyone help me to know more details about the above question?

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro